# Angular 2 routing: empty routerLink does not work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm configuring my routing and stumbled on this issue.

I currently have these 2 routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'products', component: ProductComponent}
];
```

Am I not allowed to define an empty route? Because the code below is not working

```
<a routerlink="">Home</a>
```

What is working, is the other route `products`:

```
<a routerLink="products">Products</a>
```

I searched the internet but did not yet found a solution. Since I want to keep my url clean, I can't use the `redirectTo` option to redirect to e.g. a `home` path. I want my home url to be `www.example.com` and not `www.example.com/home`.

I hope you guys understand my question.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I see what I did wrong.

It was a typo: I used `routerlink` instead of `routerLink` in my HTML. So an empty routerLink does work with Angular 2 RC6.